# How to make message from google script to WhatsApp group?

Tags: android, api, twilio, whatsapp

As I have tried the following code for individual `SMS` at `WhatsApp`.

```
function sendSms() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var RecieverNumber = activeSheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var Message = activeSheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
  openWhatsApptab(RecieverNumber,Message);

}

function openWhatsApptab(RecieverNumber,Message){
  var url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+RecieverNumber+"&text="+Message;
  var scriptHtml = '<script>window.open("'+url+'");google.script.host.close();</script>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(scriptHtml);
  ui.setHeight(1);
  ui.setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"WhatsApp Redirection...");
}
```

**But I want this for the WhatsApp group. As send SMS from google script to my WhatsApp group**

Comment: Hi, do you manage to solve this? I'm looking solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

According to Twillo documentation, whatsapp deprecated groups API.

> WhatsApp deprecated the Groups API in April 2020. Please refer to Twilio Conversations to find out how to reach multiple WhatsApp users at the same time.

Source: https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs

Comment: I am building a solution to send one message with a pdf to three groups daily. I see the post and answer is older, and if there is any advancement on sending messages to WhatsApp groups recently? Thank You